# Generating invoice and navigating to payment processor external site with single button?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a payment form generated by a payment processor which I need to integrate and clicking on the buy button takes the user to an external site for payment.

```
<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="0" id="crypto_orderid">
<input type="submit" value="Pay with cryptocurrency" id="buy-btn">
```

So the user clicks on the button and jquery sends a request to php and order id is returned.

Jquery

```
$('#buy-btn').click(function() { 
         generate_invoice();
        });

function generate_invoice() {
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "./core/create-invoice.php",
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function() { 
            },
            success: function(res) {
                try {
                    var res = JSON.parse(res);
                    if(res.success) {
                        $("#crypto_orderid").val(res.id);
                        alert(res.id);
                        console.log(res.id);
                    } else {
                         alert("unknown error");
                    }
                } catch (e) { }
            }
        });
        }
```

But the order id doesnt go through as i can see in the external page the order id is not displayed.
However if i do this without ajax try to change the value of order id field then 11 goes though as order id.
Why does the same thing not work with ajax ?

Do i have to make another button to generate the invoice and change the form ? This cant be done with 1 button ?

```
 $('#buy-btn').click(function() { 
            generate_invoice();
    });
 function generate_invoice() {
        $("#crypto_orderid").val(11);
}
```

Comment: Ajax is an async function call. So other stuff can be done while the success method waits to be called when the server replies. So your `click` handler is continuing to completion

Comment: Does `res.id` really have a value? Probably better to use onSubmit on the form rather than onClick, too

Comment: it has i did prevent default and it printed the value